# Result Generation on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have this problem wherein my model returns an object but when in the controller it can't seem to find that field, i always get this error **"Trying to get property of non-object"** but when i tried to var_dump() the result return from my model there are values. I can't seem to understand why i can't access it. Is it connected to active records?.

The following is my Model.

```
public function retrieve($user_id = FALSE)
{
    if($user_id === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('login');
        return $query->row();
    }
    else 
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('login',array('account_id'=>$user_id));
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Here is the code snippet of my controller, the part where i tried to access my Model

```
    $this->load->model('account');
    $acc = $this->account->retrieve($sess_userid);
    var_dump($this->account->retrieve($sess_userid));
    echo $acc->user_id;
```

**Note that $sess_userid has a value. its a Number**

Anyone got an idea to this problem?

UPDATED

**print_r()**

```
Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [account_id] => 2000005
            [userid] => admin
            [user_pass] => d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997
            [sex] => M
            [email] => admin@ignitero.com
            [group_id] => 99
            [admin] => 1
            [restrictions] => 0
            [state] => 0
            [unban_time] => 0
            [expiration_time] => 0
            [logincount] => 0
            [lastlogin] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [last_ip] =>
            [birthdate] => 0000-00-00
            [character_slots] => 0
            [pincode] =>
            [pincode_change] => 0
        )
)
```

**var_dump()**

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#23 (18) { 
        ["account_id"]=> string(7) "2000005" 
        ["userid"]=> string(5) "admin" 
        ["user_pass"]=> string(40) "d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997" 
        ["sex"]=> string(1) "M" 
        ["email"]=> string(18) "admin@ignitero.com" 
        ["group_id"]=> string(2) "99" 
        ["admin"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["restrictions"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["state"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["unban_time"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["expiration_time"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["logincount"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["lastlogin"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
        ["last_ip"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["birthdate"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" 
        ["character_slots"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["pincode"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["pincode_change"]=> string(1) "0" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: do you have user_id in the table because you are assigning in account_id else getting all the records

Comment: just print_r($acc); and let us know what u r getting..??

Comment: Can you paste what you are getting in the var_dump?

Comment: pleasse see my udpate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are returning the object you should use row as you are getting a single record.

```
public function retrieve($user_id = FALSE)
{
    if($user_id === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('login');
        return $query->result();
    }
    else 
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('login',array('account_id'=>$user_id));
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

and access it like this

```
echo $acc->user_id;
```

If you think the condition should return multiple rows than you can access it like this

```
return $query->result();
```

and

```
echo $acc[0]->user_id;
echo $acc[1]->user_id;
echo $acc[2]->user_id;
```

Comment: yes i am returning a single object because is row() but how come i can't access or it states that userid doesnt exist in fact it does on the database

Comment: See this `return $query->result();` it is returning array of objects that's why it is saying trying to get property of non-object because the return thing is array which contains object. Use `return $query->row();`

Comment: but it doesn't return result() cuz it enters the first condition

Comment: by the way ur example above is different from mine

Comment: @lemoncodes my answer is quite clear you only need to see where you are making a mistake

Comment: i don't see why u exchange the row() in the first condition, that function accept a variable, and i have passed a variable